# Qlik: How to create dynamic custom segments?

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have a data source like this:

```
ID  Product   Age
1   Amazon    18
2   Google    19
3   Facebook  20
4   Apple     21
5   Apple     22
6   Google    23
7   Amazon    25
8   Google    25
9   Facebook  27
10  Apple     29
11  Apple     28
12  Google    31
13  Amazon    32
14  Google    33
15  Facebook  34
```

And I want to create custom age segments like this (My visualization should look like this):

```
                                  Product
Custom Age Group    Amazon  Facebook    Google  Apple
18-21                  1       1          1       1
22-25                  1       0          2       1
26-30                  0       1          0       2
31-34                  1       1          2       0
```

The user should be able to dynamically set the age groups.

For example, if the user wants to look at `18-25` and `28-34` age groups, the user should be able to make the changes on their own. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but you could creat an inline table like this :

```
LOAD * INLINE [
Age, AgeGroup
18, 18-21
19, 18-21
20, 18-21
21, 18-21
22, 22-25
23, 22-25
...
];
```